# Parameter Of Message array parameter not accessed

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to import the gmail message in my servlets and parsing the mail as by their Subject for this I declared the a normal java class as Mail and declaring a method receive in it and calling the same function in the java servlets conneciton is been established very well messages being imported in Message[] array and then to Message msg....
but after that like msg.getSubject does works fine

```
try{
        Properties prop=new Properties();
         prop.put("mail.imap.host", host);
          prop.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
         // prop.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");

          //SSl Properties
          prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
          prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback","false");
          prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port",String.valueOf(993));


          /*Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(prop, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(email, pass);
                }
            }) ;*/
        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);

          //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
          Store store = emailSession.getStore("imap");

          store.connect(email, pass);

          //create the folder object and open it
          /*Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
          emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);*/
          IMAPFolder folder=(IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
          folder.open(folder.READ_ONLY);

          // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
          Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
          System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

          for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
             Message message = messages[i];
         //    System.out.println(message.getContentType()+"\t"+message.getContent()
           //        +"\n"+message.getFrom());

             if(message.getSubject().matches("Offline message sent by")){
                 System.out.println("++++++++++++++   PATTERN     MATCHES    ++++++++++++");
                 result="";
                 result=i+""+message.getContentType()+"\n"+message.getContent();


                 System.out.println(result);
             }
            }
```

the error basically occured at

```
 for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
             Message message = messages[i];


             if(message.getSubject().matches("Offline message sent by")){
                 System.out.println("++++++++++++++   PATTERN     MATCHES    ++++++++++++");
                 result="";
                 result=i+""+message.getContentType()+"\n"+message.getContent();


                 System.out.println(result);
             }
            }
```

Comment: *the error basically occured at* - what error?